# What are the different ways that an Oracle database can be queried and be immediately streamed to a file in Java?

Tags: java, database, spring, oracle

The code that I am working with primarily uses Spring and jdbcTemplate as a way to query the database.

As a non-working example, but just to get the idea across of how I get data and display it on my website...
There will be some object called Bike.

```
List<bikeObject> bikes = new ArrayList<>();
List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(bikeQuery));
for (Map<String<Object> row : rows){
    bikeObject b = new bikeObject();
    b.setProperty((String row.get(-property-));
    ....
    bikes.push(bikeObject)
}
```

However, sometimes the query can be too large and my computer can run out of memory or the database query can timeout.

A solution that was brought to my attention was to just query it into a ResultSet and then iterate through and stream it directly to a file. I can scrap the display on the website and just let the user download an excel table on a click of a button.

I see that I can use something like (copied from the oracle site)

```
OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
ods.setURL(url);
ods.setUser(user);
ods.setPassword(password);
String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:scott/tiger@//myhost:1521/orcl");
ods.setURL(URL);
Connection conn = ods.getConnection();
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

from here I think I can just iterate through rset and write to a file using BufferedWriter.

The issue I have with this is that my code is pretty consistent so how would I set the URL/User/Password from the Spring properties file that I have? I don't want to type it in the file on a  one time occasion.

Also, is this the best way to approach this problem? Can I write to file using jdbcTemplate + ResultSet? I'm stuck on finding a way how.

Slight update:
I assume that the query (passed off from someone else) is optimal and that all the data is necessary. This leaves me with the conclusion of streaming the query results straight to file. Is there a way I can do this with jdbcTemplate or do I have to do it via

```
Connection conn = ods.getConnection();
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(swSb);
```

And iterating through it on a next() basis?

Answer (score 0):

You don't describe well the problem: Do you really need all data? is database setup with indexes and is the query optimal?

You can use oracle pagination support http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2007/07-jan/o17asktom-093877.html  so the user get first X elements.

If you really need all data and it is a lot I would avoid mapping to an object specially object instantiation inside a loop. 
It would help if you could tell how many rows are you expecting

Comment: Sure. The data is all necessary, but sometimes depending on the query (like not like this one) it can be very small.

The query is optimal and at most I can expect an a full excel sheet of data with 47 columns, which is ~180 mb.

With this stream to file route I am avoiding mapping in an object.. so I think that leaves me with the question of if I can set it up in relation to my Spring setup?

Comment: Something doesn't add-up, it is only a few rows but it makes 180mb? What kind of data is it? you can write resultSet to  csv  or run a sql statement that export to a file itself.

Comment: No, it can range in number of rows. At max it can be ~180 mb (a million rows) but at it's lowest it can be 1-2 kb, like one or two rows. It just depends on the query to the database.

Comment: What is the final format of the data? you probably need to introduce a middleware with cache. Do you need to do a lot of DB joins, sort, filter? or is it one table only?  Would storing the data in the DB in the final format work?

Comment: I don't think I have access to it, I only have access to read from the database and then to write it to probably a .csv file. Yes it goes through different DB joins, sorts, filters.. I'm not sure if storing it in the final format would work, can you elaborate?

Comment: I don't think saving to a file will help since you will have to load and represent it anyway. regarding setting the connection you can use spring datasources: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html  if you are sure the query is good then you can only help avoiding creating complex objects in java multiple times. try to work with raw data